# How to deploy next.js 9 to aws lambda

Tags: reactjs, deployment, aws-lambda, next.js

I am developing a project with next.js9. I have some problems and questions. I would like to deploy my next.js 9 project to AWS lambda.

1. official next.js 9 doc tell me "each page in the pages directory becomes a serverless lambda." Above library is not working like doc. How can I deploy from each page to each lambda?
2. What is reasonable solution to deployment? please someone who use nextjs 9 in production level help me.
3. I am using this library https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js.
   it's working well. but all options are fixed. I would like to deploy my project to Tokyo region. but I have no idea how to change region. always deploy to N. virginia region. I already checked doc but I think they don't have options. and test like this yml file.

serverless.yml

```
myNextApplication:
  component: serverless-next.js
region: ap-northeast-1
```

but it was not working. if someone know how to change region with serverless-next.js. Please help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried to search the problem among nextjs GitHub examples? I guess you may find your answer there.https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/Examples

Comment: @Afsanefda There is no example in there. anyway Thank you.

Comment: Hi @hahaha. 
1st question: running `npm run dev` are you able to see your application working?
2nd question: when you say "Above library is not working like doc" what you mean? That you get some error from console or other kind of behaviour?

Comment: For the `region` problem you could try to run `serverless` deploy command with `--stage` command line option where you specify which aws profile you want to use. Inside that profile you may try to set the region and see if works.

Comment: @Pierfrancesco I mean "each page in the pages directory becomes a serverless lambda." this. this is micro service deployment. How can I do that?

Comment: You can try using SST framework to deploy your Next.js app. It's a framework on top of AWS CDK, so you have full control over region, and a knob for every property of the underlying AWS resource. Here's an example https://serverless-stack.com/examples/how-to-create-a-nextjs-app-with-serverless.html

Answer (score 12):

Deploying Next.js to AWS Lambda needs a layer of abstraction because Next.js is designed to work as a Node.js server in the first place.

Vercel does this with a thing called [`now-node-bridge`](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/master/packages/now-node-bridge/src/bridge.ts) which basically starts a local Node.js http-server inside the Lambda function and then create a request from the Lambda invoke event.

Here is a simplified flow chart what happens when you run a request against a Next.js app that is deployed on Vercel:
[image]

While Next.js is Open Source the proxy that does the conversion from HTTP Requests to Lambda Events at Vercel is not. That is the reason why a serverless deployment to AWS is still a tricky task while Vercel internally also uses AWS Lambda for their deployments.

## Deployment to AWS Lambda

While the Serverless framework still might be the most popular choice at the moment, I created a simple to use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) module for this task.
Terraform is an Open Source CLI application for managing Cloud-Resources in providers like AWS.

With Terraform installed it is as simple as this:

1. Go to your Next.js app and install this helper:

   ```
   npm i -D tf-next     # npm or
   yarn add -D tf-next  # yarn
   ```
2. Add the following script `tf-next` to your `package.json` of your Next.js app:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "dev": "next",
       "build": "next build",
       "start": "next start",
   +   "tf-next": "tf-next build"
      }
   }
   ...
   ```
3. Create a new `main.tf` with the following content right next to your `package.json`:

   ```
   # main.tf

   terraform {
     required_providers {
       aws = {
         source  = "hashicorp/aws"
         version = "~> 3.0"
       }
     }
   }

   # Main region where the resources should be created in
   provider "aws" {
     region = "us-east-1"
   }

   module "tf_next" {
     source  = "dealmore/next-js/aws"
   }
   ```
4. Create an [AWS Access Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html) and expose it in the terminal:

   ```
   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   ```
5. Build the app and deploy it to AWS with terraform:

   ```
    terraform init    # Only needed on the first time running Terraform

    yarn tf-next      # Build the next.js app
    terraform plan    # See what resources Terraform will create
    terraform apply   # Deploy the App to your AWS account
   ```

You can change the region in the `main.tf` to any AWS region that [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html) Lambdas and the region that you define there is the region where your Lambdas are deployed to.

For more information please see the GitHub Page: [AWS Next.js Terraform module on GitHub](https://github.com/dealmore/terraform-aws-next-js)

Comment: This works great, thanks! What should be done if after than I will update the app code and want to redeploy? Would running just `terraform apply` suffice in this case?

Comment: To update the app on AWS both commands (`yarn tf-next` and `terraform apply`) are required for each update. `yarn tf-next` builds the static files and Lambdas from the source code while `terraform apply` is responsible for deploying the previously built artifacts to AWS.

Answer (score 7):

There is a webpack plugin, that can help [next-aws-lambda-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/vincent-herlemont/next-aws-lambda-webpack-plugin).

1. This plugin generate for each page a directory with [the serverless code of the Next.JS](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/build-target#server-target)
2. This plugin do not use [Serverless framwork](https://serverless.com/) so you can use native AWS deployment solution for your infrastructure like : [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) ou [AWS cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/cloudformation/) for your deployment and benefit from AWS support.
3. With AWS native solution deployment you are free to choose any wanted region.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Your edit seems to just extend the list of mentioned plugins. Please try to demonstrate, instead of only adding details to the description.

Comment: I have try to answer the first three points of @hahaha, there are informal. Maybe look with more attention the question (there are two parts). No personal e.g -

Comment: I misunderstood your edit as an attempt to actually improve the general style of your answer. So you are going to stay with only mentioning libraries without demonstrating?

Comment: I am sorry, but I misunderstood what you want to say by demonstration in this contexte ? An example ?

Answer (score 2):

this plugin you're using for deployment is using lambda@edge and this operates region-less:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html

> Lambda@Edge is an extension of AWS Lambda, a compute service that lets
>   you execute functions that customize the content that CloudFront
>   delivers. You can author Node.js or Python functions in one Region,
>   US-East-1 (N. Virginia), and then execute them in AWS locations
>   globally that are closer to the viewer, without provisioning or
>   managing servers. Lambda@Edge scales automatically, from a few
>   requests per day to thousands per second.

If you like to have more flexibility in you serverless deployment, use the webpack plugin that is mentioned here in the thread:

https://github.com/vincent-herlemont/next-aws-lambda-webpack-plugin

Together with the serverless framework you can define manually, for every NextJs page, a lambda function (not Lambda@Edge) and deploy it to you AWS account in your region.

Comment: It still uses router lambda which routes to requests the SSR lambdas, it still uses Lambda@Edge

Answer (score -2):

1. I don't still have idea.

2,3. serverless-next.js is a little reasonable. I made issue github. Contributor answer me like following. I understood the concept of the framework.

https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js#my-lambda-is-deployed-to-us-east-1-how-can-i-deploy-it-to-another-region